# Need help stopping countdown if a cell has a date in it

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have this formula for counting down to a due date. =IF(ISBLANK(J18), "", J18-TODAY()) 
This works how I want it to for the countdown, so I don't want it changed. I just can't figure out how to add an IF statement to it to stop counting down if I have a closed date in L18.

Comment: What do you want to write if L18 has closed Date? and in which cell is your Formula (is it in L18? or no)

Comment: Yass, I want the number in I18 to freeze, so it can be used for lessons learned.

Comment: Can you clarify what is a "closed" date?  Are you referring to halting all of the action if L18 contains a date, or do you mean that certain dates are "closed for business", like say on a weekend, so you just want to exclude an indicated date from the countdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to want to enable iterative calculations.  This is found in Excel Options under Formulas:

[image]

Then you will create a circular reference. If your formula was in K18 you would use this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(L18),IF(ISBLANK(J18), "", J18-TODAY()),K18)
```

Replace the K18 with the cell in which the formula is placed, you want to force the circular reference.

Comment: Scott, will this freeze the number in the countdown cell? I would like that for lessons learned.

Comment: Yes as long as there is a value in L18 the countdown will remain as is.

Answer (score 0):

In case your Formula: =IF(ISBLANK(J18), "", J18-TODAY()) is in a different cell than L18, you can use the following:

`=IF(L18>0,"Closed",IF(ISBLANK(J18), "", J18-TODAY()))`

You can change `Closed` to whatever you want when you have Close Date in L18